# Using a large CSV file as input for a website

Tags: php, html, database, csv

I do not know if this is the right spot to ask my question perhaps I should do it another community but I got a question regarding implementing a website that deals with a large CSV file as input.

I am willing to program a website that have a CSV file as input to generate all kinds of data on my website. Think of each entry has their own geolocations etc. In the end I want to create an informative website where the data of the CSV file is used.

Now I want to know what approach might be the best to do this. I can imagine that storing this CSV file within a Database and retrieving data with PHP might take forever due to large loading time when the website is making a call. Can anyone tell me what approach might work when working which such large CSV file?

To give you an idea. In my CSV file I have the following data:

```
#, Soccer Club, Street adress, Highest competition,..
1, Soccer club 1, adress 123, 3th division,..
2, Soccer club 2, adress 456, 6th division,..
etc.
```

Now I want to create a webste that use this data and create all kinds of marker points on a map. I do know how to code this the only problem is that I am searching for a fast way of reading and using the data without having my website to load a long time to generate this information. I did not try it yet but before I spend to much time on it I was wondering which advise could you give me?

BTW Think of CSV files of the size of 1GB/2GB

Comment: Database access is always going to be better/faster than file I/O, especially with large datasets.

Comment: and you can not process 1GB/2GB data at a time

Comment: @MineshPatel You can if you have lots of resources.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to import the CSV in to a database table not store the whole file as is and then run queries on it. Databases are optimised and meant for these things.

Comment: I have processed bigger files. with right indexes your queries can be fast.

Comment: Problem is not reading from database, but processing file itself.

Comment: @ShujaShabandri Justinas refering to reading and inserting data in db

Comment: If its reading and inserting data, its a one time job which doesn't happen on every request. If you use MySQL you can load directly in to the database

Comment: using LOAD DATA INFILE